# Plupload - Add Files not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, plupload, html4

I cant get plupload add files to open the file selection dialog in IE8.  It works fine in Firefox.

I've tried a few different ideas I've come across:

1. Changing Z-index
2. Flash and Html4 as runtimes
3. Manually triggering the button
4. Refreshing the uploader
5. Making sure my container div wasnt hidden

Here is my code:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'html5,html4',
        multipart: true,
        source: 'AccountDocument',
        browse_button: 'pickfiles',

        container: 'container', // ... or DOM Element itself
        url: "Home/UploadAttachment",

        filters: {
            max_file_size: '10mb',
        },

        flash_swf_url: 'http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/moxie/master/bin/flash/Moxie.cdn.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: 'http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/moxie/master/bin/silverlight/Moxie.cdn.xap',

        preinit: attachCallbacks,


        init: {
            PostInit: function () {

                $('#filelist').innerHTML = '';

                $('#uploadfiles').onclick = function () {
                    $('#uploadfiles').text('Uploading...');

                   submit(false, 'AccountDocument', 'frmAccountDocument' + r, BusinessUnitID);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        uploader.settings.multipart_params = { accountDocumentID: $("#ID").val(), description: $("#AttachmentDescription").val() };
                        uploader.start();
                        $('#uploadfiles').text('UPLOAD');

                   }, 500); 
                    return false;
                };
            },


            Browse: function (up) {
                alert('hi');
                // Called when file picker is clicked
                log('[Browse]');
            },

            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                $('#tblAttachmentDisplay').show();
                $('#uploadfile').show();
                $('#pickfiles').hide();


                plupload.each(files, function (file) {
                    $('#tblAttachmentDisplay #trUploadRow').show();
                    $('#tblAttachmentDisplay #trUploadRow #tdUploadFileName').text(file.name);
                    $('#tblAttachmentDisplay #trUploadRow #tdUploadDescription').html('<input type="text" class="text-box" value ="Please enter a description" id="AttachmentDescription" />');
                    $("#tblAttachmentDisplay #trUploadRow #tdUploadDescription #AttachmentDescription").focus().select();

                });
            },

            Error: function (up, err) {
                $('#console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
            }
        }
    });




    uploader.bind("Init", function (up, params) {
        $("#runtime").html("<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>");
    });

    uploader.init();

    uploader.refresh();
```

```
<table id="tblAttachment">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <div id="filelist"></div>
            <a id="pickfiles" href="#" class="lnkHotLightBlue txtBoldSubHeader" style="color:#5191CD;display:block;position: relative; z-index: 999999">Upload a File</a>
            <div id="container"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>



<div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
<div id="runtime">
                        No runtime was found !
</div>
```

Comment: HTML markup was cutoff for some reason

Comment: <table id="tblAttachment">

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <div id="filelist"></div>
            <a id="pickfiles" href="#" class="lnkHotLightBlue txtBoldSubHeader" style="color:#5191CD;display:block;position: relative; z-index: 999999">Upload a File</a>
            <div id="container"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>



<div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
<div id="runtime">
                        No runtime was found !
                    </div>

Comment: Well, do you have Flash installed and does it work in IE8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Yes flash is installed and plupload shows it as the current runtime, but does not work.